# Next.js Static Site Generator but pure html

Tags: next.js, static-site-generation

How can I get Next.js to generate pure html as the page is rendered and not all this extra overhead. My index page is just a list of links. I just want index.html. Is that possible?

[image: Output]

Edit : How to get around api routes not working with export? I have a json file with list of {url,title} that I want to render in index.html statically

Comment: I think that what you receive is static generated page (with JS). What you describe is something like a snapshot, when we used it with ReactJS to generate content for hydration. Example: https://github.com/stereobooster/react-snap

Comment: I found out I could import the json file directly - https://trinbagotechie.blogspot.com/2023/06/part-2-example-of-using-nextjs-for.html